# WxPython ScrolledWindow scrollbars - how to make visibly larger?

Tags: python, wxpython, scrolledwindow

I'd like to make the scrollbars on a WxPython ScrolledWindow, visibly larger - by that, I mean more pixels wider, so instead of, say, only being 5 pixels wide (and hard for me to mouse-click on), make them 50 pixels wide.

All of the documentation/examples I can find, are about making the scrollbar take up a larger section of the *object* that is being *scrolled* - which is not what I'm looking for.

It's possible there is no such option, I certainly can't find anything that remotely relates to it, in the [Scrolling Docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Scrolled.html#wx.Scrolled.SetScrollbars).

Comment: A `wx.ScrollBar` has a `SetSize` which will determine the width and height, allowing you to define the physical size but the Grunt part, the active Thumb and slider is almost certainly defined by the `Theme` you use on your desktop. These are editable. On linux start by looking in /usr/share/themes, For each theme there will be a `gtkrc` file for gtk2 and for gtk3 a `css` file. These will define the scrollbar dimensions, along with a host of other goodies.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony if I read that right, you are confirming that WxPython *itself*, does not have a way to make the clickable size of a scrollbar, any larger?

Comment: I believe that to be the case. You can make the `thumb` longer but not wider by adjusting the `thumbSize`.